# WebAPI REST - not calling correct controller when using multiple parameters

Tags: vb.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

Having a bit of an issue getting the Web API to call the correct handler when I pass parameters with my Get request.

My basic handler is this:

```
Public Function GetAllASTM05Report() As IEnumerable(Of ASTM05Report)

    Return repository.GetAll()

End Function
```

And that returns all records just fine.

But now I want to add this:

```
Public Function GetASTM05ReportWithSearch(sortField As String, searchOrder As String, searchField As String, searchValue As String) As IEnumerable(Of ASTM05Report)

    Return repository.GetAllWithSearch(0, 25, sortField, searchOrder, searchField, searchValue)

End Function
```

But when I try this URI:

```
http://localhost/AdminAPI/api/astm05report?sortField=reportId&sortOrder=ASC&searchField=ReportID&searchValue=rr
```

I expect it to use GetASTM05ReportWithSearch() but it ends up going to GetAllASTM05Report().

If I remove GetAllASTM05Report() then I get an error: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI.

One person supposedly got it working by passing an object like this:

```
Public Function GetASTM05ReportWithSearch(<FromBody> values As SearchValues)

    Return repository.GetAllWithSearch(0, 25, values.sortField, values.searchOrder, values.searchField, values.searchValue)

End Function
```

But I got an error: Multiple actions were found that match the request

If I remove GetAllASTM05Report(), GetASTM05ReportWithSearch() does fire, but values is nothing.

I have not changed the default routing tables and my client JS does not like the true REST syntax like:

```
http://localhost/AdminAPI/api/astm05report/reportId/ASC/ReportID/rr
```

So I do not want to explore solutions which require such routing table mods.

Help! What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Jon Susiak called it - misnamed parameter. Embarrassing!

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: Your URI with the query parameters should work just fine.  I suspect there is just a typo somewhere.  Try with just one query parameter, and once you get that working add more.

Comment: Your method has parameter searchOrder but your querystring has sortOrder.

Comment: Jon, You got it! Add an answer so I can mark it as answer and get you your credit.